# Postgresql lost tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database on my centos server.
Unfortunately since yesterday, in all existing schemas, all the tables are lost.
I saw log file and there was an unexpected reboot in recent days, probably a crash of the o.s.
Now the Postgres server it start correctly and I can view triggers, sequences and there aren't  other problems.
Can I do something to recovery these tables?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see on the PGSQL logs?

Comment: A crash should never affect PostgreSQL data contents unless you have severe filesystem corruption or you were running postgres with fsync=off set. My guess is that actually you have more than one postgres installed, and when you restarted a different one got started up, so you need to find and start your other install.

Comment: `UNLOGGED` tables will be reset to empty after a crash, but they will not vanish.

Comment: There is only one Postgres installation. 
The folder relative to this db, under "data" seems quite heavy so I think that data May Be there.
The only thing you can't read are the tables.
 Exist a Recovery Procedures to repair these Tables?